# I couldn't get past this error in open cv

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: Did you read the error and understand it? Did you check why the assertion failed? Did you post a [mre] and a sample image so we could reproduce your problem?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

This problem says that an assertion is failed. If the file doesn't exist in the given path, cv2 returns this error. So check if the file exists in your given path.

Comment: I got this error when file exists